# MessageBeep() not working on 64-bit Server2008

Tags: c++, windows, api, windows-server-2008, win64

I recently found that in a 32-bit windows application running on Server 2008 R2 64-bit, the notification sound (produced via a C++ call to MessageBeep( MB_ICONEXCLAMATION )) no longer produces a sound. Sounds in general work and the profile has been loaded with default windows sound settings in the Control Panel. Works fine on Win7 64-bit, so I assume its something server specific. Any suggestions for narrowing it down?

Comment: You are not using a "remote client", by any chance? In which case you should use "Beep" instead.

Comment: Lots of google hits for "messagebeep server 2008".  Don't expect anybody here to just repeat this.  At least work down the common causes and make it obvious in your question that their workarounds didn't help.

Comment: Turn the volume up from 0 :)

Comment: Interesting article at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx regarding how Beep() is a thin wrapper to programming an 8254 PIC chip that essentially boils down to _now when you call the Beep() API instead of manipulating the 8254 chip the call is re-routed into a user mode agent which actually plays the sounds._

Comment: I am not using a remote client, however, I have substituted a call to Beep() instead of MessageBeep() to see if that was the problem (it made no difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usable workaround:

```
#include <MMSystem.h>
PlaySound( (LPCTSTR) SND_ALIAS_SYSTEMEXCLAMATION, NULL, SND_ALIAS_ID );
```

Comment: This does not work for me on me 2019 WIN10 machine -- Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.557], SDK "Latest Verson"

Comment: Look under Control Panel, Sounds, Change system sounds and make sure you have them defined. It works fine on a WIn10 Pro machine in my office

Comment: Thanks  for a reply. This then means SND_ALIAS_ .... does not guarantee a sound? Am I correct in assuming a bit more WIN32 digging is required for funtionality like: "Is there a sound scheme on this machine?", or "does this event has a sound associated?" ... when PlaySound returns false, GetLastError message is the ever helpfull one "Wrong Parameter" ... Of course I can include a tiny wav into this app rersource and use that if there is no system sound ... but...